# Не срабатывает OnItemSelectedListener в Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Есть `Spinner`, в нем более 30 item'ов. При выборе любого из них не срабатывает `OnItemSelectedListener`.

В чем может быть ошибка? В логах ошибок нет.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.btnJanr);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraylistGenre);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setSelected(true);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("Tags", "IdItem" + String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
});
```

Comment: ну во-первых уберите строчку - adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Убирал, но ни чего не изменилось.

Comment: это не должно было исправить ошибку - это лишнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `setOnItemClickListener()`. Прекрасно работает:

```
List<String> arraylistGenre = new ArrayList();
arraylistGenre.add("Привет");
arraylistGenre.add("Привет");
arraylistGenre.add("Привет");
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraylistGenre);
spinner.setSelected(true);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("Tags", "IdItem" + String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
});
```

Comment: А как насчет объяснения почему это стоит пробовать?

Comment: Тут вроде как просто не используется множественный выбор и из-за этого предложил.....

Comment: Я не против вашей идеи, равно как и я не сведущ в теме `Spinner`'ов. Однако, по моему мнению, объяснением ответа должно быть что-то более осмысленное, чем просто код и "попробуй" или "вот так работает".

Comment: @Regent  onitemSelectedListener используется для других задач, когда элементы списка (Spinner'а) реализуют интерфейс Checkable.

Comment: Кстати, "вот так вот работает" очень помогло, как оказалось не было дефолтного значения в arraylistGenre, т.к. он создавался после обработки API и spinner только после этого брал те значения, и когда добавили в ручную один элемент в arraylistGenre все заработало) больше спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот это

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.btnJanr);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraylistGenre);
  spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // сюда и логи можно поставить

     }
  });
```

Comment: у меня данный метод вылетает в ошибку java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.